# Is it possible to get my HP touchsmart 520 working with Ubuntu 18

Tags: drivers, hp

I want my touchscreen working but I can’t find a solution, dus anybody know were to find drivers or something that wil make it work?

Comment: "Ubuntu 18" is imprecise. Which Ubntu release are you running?  `lsb_release -r`. You can see a list of your hardware with `sudo lshw`. Read `man lshw` to see more options.

Comment: It is 18.04.3 lts (latest version)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit question and add more info in there. Comment could be cleaned up later.

Answer (score 0):

Googling touchsmart 520 shows a 2011 device. If it does not work already, I doubt you will find drivers for it. Even if you do find them, linux "external" drivers are source code for very old linux kernel, thus will most likely not compile with 2018 kernels.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that, it’s an older computer, I wanted to try it with linux